# Can a background android service be configured via GUI?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, service, android-intentservice

What I'm trying to do is have a background service running permanently after installing but supposing that the sensor is scheduled to work every 10 minutes, I want the user to have an interface which he can use to change the delay.
So the service itself doesn't need an activity to run (if I want the delay to be always 10 minutes) but when the user clicks on the icon of the app, an activity is called that allows the user to configure the delay of the service and then when the user exits that interface the service goes back to running in the background with the new delay value.

Comment: I use a preference activity to customize my service, so yes, you can

Comment: Of course you can.  You just need a mechanism to tell the service to check for new values (or need the service to do so periodically).